# How should i structure a function that takes a pandas dataframe and writes to its columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a function that iterates through a dataframe, and takes each row's value as an argument. For example:

My pandas dataframe is as follows:

```
category  sales  met_sales
fruit     100    False
books     200    False
fruit     300    False
```

I have a dictionary: `required_sales = {'fruit':150, 'books':200}`

The output I want is this:

```
category  sales  met_sales
fruit     100    False
books     200    True
fruit     300    True
```

Is it correct to structure my function like that?

```
def met_sales(df, dict):
    for row in df:
        if row.sales > required_sales[row.category]:
             #update met_sales column
             row.met_sales = True
```

Then, I can simply call `met_sales(df,required_sales)` to update my DataFrame.

Is this a good way of using self created functions to modify my DataFrame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for dictionary and compare with column `sales`:

```
df['met_sales'] = df['sales'] >= df['category'].map(required_sales)
print (df)
  category  sales  met_sales
0    fruit    100      False
1    books    200       True
2    fruit    300       True
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['category'].map(required_sales))
0    150
1    200
2    150
Name: category, dtype: int64
```

Function:

Dont use `dict` as variable name as it is a reserved word for builtin python `dict`.

```
def met_sales(df, d):
    df['met_sales'] = df['sales'] >= df['category'].map(d)
    return df

df1 = met_sales(df,required_sales)
print (df1)
  category  sales  met_sales
0    fruit    100      False
1    books    200       True
2    fruit    300       True
```

**Notice**:

It is necessary that all values of `category` are present in your dict, else missing values are returned for not existing keys:

```
required_sales = {'fruit':150}

print (df['category'].map(required_sales))
0    150.0
1      NaN
2    150.0
Name: category, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Often, my task requires me to look up other DataFrame or data structures to update my DataFrame. Is it correct to say that I should not use any self created functions at all, and use a mixture of .map(), creating new columns, and boolean logic to modify my dataframe?

Comment: @GenTan - hmmm, it depends. If performance is important or large data (10k+ rows) then better is use `map`, because functions are obviously slow, map is faster.

Comment: If always few rows it is up to you, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002) is possible check table of priority generally in pandas.